# SignalR Client - Handler for message that contains no event name?

Tags: c#, websocket, event-handling, signalr

I am coding a SignalR Hub Client to get data from a web-service, and for one of the more important methods I am invoking on their server, the message I get back contains no "M: eventName" line of the sort I am using to handle the other message types (just "R:[Data] and I:[0]"). I can see the message data is all there when I enable Tracing, but how do I go about handling this with no eventName?

example:

```
`HubProxy.On<DataClass>("???event-name-here???", update => Console.WriteLine("OUTPUT");`
```

Message Trace:

`23:02:34.9119843 - e1ef32d1-d374-4d7d-82b4-011d906cb096 - WS: OnMessage({"R":{"MarketName":null,"Nounce":136096,"Buys":[{"Quantity":1261.89236694,"Rate":0.00567987},{"Quantity":17.66436734,"Rate":0.00565000},{"Quantity":0.35424250,"Rate":0.00564585},{"Quantity":148.53138590,"Rate":0.00564100},{"Quantity":114.03031557,"Rate":0.00564000},{"Quantity":823.55802148,"Rate":0.00563998},{"Quantity":92.11307737,"Rate":0.00563997},{"Quantity":439.17714798,"Rate":0.00563990},{"Quantity":35.46237619,"Rate":0.00563978},{"Quantity":380.42279579,"Rate":0.00563777},{"Quantity":308.83819198,"Rate":0.00563600},{"Quantity":0.10951077,"Rate":0.00563433},{"Quantity":0.35548667,"Rate":0.00562609},{"Quantity":11.23857359,"Rate":0.00562082},{"Quantity":2.69321221,"Rate":0.00562011},{"Quantity":0.99414299,"Rate":0.00561891},{"Quantity":24.41591498,"Rate":0.00561500},{"Quantity":0.35673516,"Rate":0.00560640},{"Quantity":2.66949153,"Rate":0.00560500},{"Quantity":38.31222855,"Rate":0.00560000},{"Quantity":17.84436494,"Rate":0.00559000},{"Quantity":208.91357967,"Rate":0.00557050},{"Quantity":0.89792884,"Rate":0.00556837},{"Quantity":6.28868665,"Rate":0.00556555},{"Quantity":178.86139272,"Rate":0.00556301},{"Quantity":304.80171408,"Rate":0.00556300},{"Quantity":0.56409118,"Rate":0.00556122},{"Quantity":11.57184239,"Rate":0.00556069},{"Quantity":0.19164392,"Rate":0.00555933},{"Quantity":3.00000000,"Rate":0.00555560},{"Quantity":1579.01........`

Comment: You'll have to make one up. What the hack are "M, R, and I" anyways?

Comment: I am receiving the events provided from a webserver I have no control over. How do I "make one up?" (an eventname to register my handler to).

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are receiving events at all (just HTTP responses). But again; just make one up. If your call is "myRequest" then the event could be "myRequestResponse" or "foo" or whatever you want it to be. You are defining the SignalR hub; and if you *aren't* defining the signalR hub then its not a real event, as all SignalR events (which are really client method invocations) must have names.

Comment: It sounds like you dont understand the functionality of a SignalR Hub. Thanks anyway for the downvote.

Comment: I am invoking a method on the server using the method name, and I do receive a WEBSOCKET message containing the data I requested back from the server, however, I cannot handle the message (as I would with the other messages I am receiving) as it contains no eventName within. Any suggestions?

Comment: I understand the functionality of a SignalR hub far better than you can imagine. If you don't want to listen to me; that's your problem. It sounds like perhaps you are writing a custom *client* for a signalr hub; to which I would ask: why on earth would you do that?

Comment: Why wouldnt I? To consume the webservice provided by the company I am accessing data from. This particular webservice is in beta and contains no documentation. You say you understand SignalR, yet you dont understand the hubproxy.On() method?? Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Wait; you are trying to consume a signalr hub via reverse-engineering? That *almost* makes sense; though I would still suspect that the "event" you are getting is just a return value and so does not need an `On` handler.

Comment: Then how should I process it in my client?

Comment: The `Invoke` method in the C# SignalR client accounts for return values if I recall correctly; just use the return value

Comment: Yes Thanks, I used the overload version of proxy.Invoke<T>() and was able to receive the resulting return object, which was encoded within the R:[] field of the response message. You have answered my question!

Comment: Glad to help; I posted that as an answer for visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that message is not a client-invocation (what you are calling an "event") but the return value of a server call.

To use return values; use `Invoke<T>` instead of `Invoke` on the `IHubProxy` object.